# problem in <html dir="rtl"> pages and google plus one button

Tags: html, google-plus-one, right-to-left

I have a HTML page that is in rtl  with the following code and Google plus one button does not appear good in  pages.
Until the plusone.js file loaded there is a very big horizontal scroll because of dir="rtl" in html tag.
After loading plusone.js the scroll will disappear.
how can i avoid appear and disappear of this horizontal scroll.(I don't want to remove dir="rtl" from  tag)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
   <div class="g-plusone" data-size="small" data-annotation="none"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed this for my site

**my problem** was that every article page in my site had a horizontal scroll bar.
after a long investigation i found that **Google plus one button has a bug**
this bug is visible only when the page uses Direction=rtl style.

**how to fix**
as long as the bug is relevant (hopefully google will fix it soon) just add this to you'r css file

```
iframe[id^="oauth2relay"]
{
    right:100px;
}
```

this will restore the correct position for the page for any iframe that called "oauth2relay" (google plus one script)

i'm using it in my site in every article page - you can check it out - just search "oauth2relay" in any article using firebug

my site is [www.mentallica.co.il](http://www.mentallica.co.il)
article for example: [example](http://www.mentallica.co.il/article/%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%A8-%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99)

Answer (score 1):

The script does not allow you to change elements
But there is a simple solution
Instead, set the `dir = "rtl"` to the html or body to do this set for a main div

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript';    po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content" style="direction: rtl;">
   <div class="g-plusone" data-size="small" data-annotation="none"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this css to your css file, this code is work for me

```
iframe[id^="oauth2relay"] { position: fixed !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug is now fixed in the Google+ Javascript. You should no longer need to make any changes to get things to work properly.